# Oracle. Choose the initials for the format

Tags: sql, oracle

There is some table that has a field `initials`. This field can for example contain the following data:

```
Francis Bacon
F.B.
F. B.
Immanuel Kant
Immanuel  K.
I. Kant
```

I want to make a query to return data in the following format:

```
F.B.
F.B.
F.B.
I.K.
I.K.
I.K.
```

Is there any way to implement this query in oracle?

Comment: Did you try anything? Are these all of the formats the data can be in?

Comment: You could read whatever is in the table, process it with C#, and then update the table with the desired (processed) format. What if the person has three names? E.g: J. S. Bach, M. C. Escher

Comment: @PeterAbolins Why take it out of the database, process it in an external language and return it to the database when you can do exactly the same thing in the database?

Comment: @MT0 Of course... I just had a "why can't people specify exactly what they want, and show what they have tried, before posting" moment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
SELECT initials,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( initials, '(^|[[:space:]]+)([^[:space:]])[^.[:space:]]*\.?', '\2.' )
         AS short_initials
FROM   your_table
```

Output:

```
INITIALS      SHORT_INITIALS
------------- --------------
Francis Bacon F.B.
F.B.          F.B.
F. B.         F.B.
Immanuel Kant I.K.
Immanuel  K.  I.K.
I. Kant       I.K.
```

**Update**:

If you need to match the string `F.Bacon` then change the first `+` to `*`:

```
SELECT initials,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( initials, '(^|[[:space:]]*)([^[:space:]])[^.[:space:]]*\.?', '\2.' )
         AS short_initials
FROM   your_table
```

Output:

```
INITIALS      SHORT_INITIALS
------------- --------------
F.Bacon       F.B.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a character followed by zero or more characters and zero or more blanks or points and replace this by the character followed by a point:

```
select
  name,
  regexp_replace(name, '([[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]*[ .]*', '\1.', 1, 0) as initials
from names;
```

Comment: You may also need to include hyphens and apostrophes in the acceptable name characters to match `O'Brien` or `Smith-Jones`.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a full solution but something like this will work if you want a query without RegExp

```
select 
case
     when charindex(' ',name) <>0 AND CHARINDEX('.',NAME)<>0 then substring(name,1,1) +'.'+ substring(substring(name,charindex(' ',name),len(name)),2,1) 
     when charindex('.',name) <>0 and charindex('.',name)<>len(name)  then substring(name,1,1) +'.'+ substring(substring(name,charindex('.',name),len(name)),2,1) 
end from @temp
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` and `LEN` are not Oracle functions - you want `SUBSTR`, `INSTR` and `LENGTH` instead. This will also not work if there are two adjacent space characters like in the `Immanuel  K.` example.

Comment: As mentioned,This is not a full solution but something like this will work if you want a query without RegExp

Comment: Please show the full solution that produces the expected results (in Oracle - you can always [test it online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d51cd/5)) for all the OP's sample data - otherwise it is not a solution.